# centOS7 netinstall with kickstart fails to get installation source

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7

I'm trying to install `CentOS7` using a `kickstart` file with a `VM`. I am using a `netinstall` version of the `ISO`.

When I try to put the URL in the `kickstart` file, it will take a long time to check the installation source, and then fail.

I have checked the `ISO`, installing successfully without `kickstart` and using this address for the source:

> url --url="http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/"

However, when using kickstart file, I install and then fail with below error message -

> Error setting up base repository

Even if I manually type it in after it errors out.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I have reduced my `kickstart` file to just that one line and it still shows the same behaviour.  I don't have this problem with `kickstart` using the minimal or full install `ISO`'s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning Linux so I didn't realize you could switch into another screen and monitor the install/run commands simultaneously.

After doing so I realised it wouldn't resolve names.

My DNS is dead/isn't responding.  Used kickstart to manually assign another DNS server to the interface.  This allowed the install to resolve the url.  This would explain why the install worked with the netinstall iso on its own, as it was using default settings.

Hope this helps someone.